# How to find the HTML element id of text field pop up window?

Tags: java, html, selenium

I am trying to automate browser using Selenium in Java. However I am unable to find the element ID of a text field in pop up window to call it in Selenium Java.

The text field whos HTML element ID that I am trying to find is Project (as seen in attached photo)

Selenium script:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("project-name")).sendKeys("TEST: Automatation by Selenium");
```

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: did you check if Id exists on the field ? also you can try by the name of field

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("project-field")).sendKeys("TEST: Automatation by Selenium");
```

Are you sure that the `id` is `project-name` and not `project-field`? In my Jira template `project-field` is used as `id`.